# MySQL Getting row numbers of table inside subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one query where I need to have number of rows of an table by particular ID:

```
SELECT
    (CAST(`ot`.`value` AS DECIMAL(6,2))) AS `value`,
    `op`.`orders_id`,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS `total`
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT
                `op2`.`concert_date`
            FROM
                `orders_products` `op2`
            WHERE
                `op2`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
            AND
                `op2`.`concert_date` <> ''
            GROUP BY CONCAT(`op2`.`concert_date`,' ',`op2`.`concert_time`)
        ) AS `e`
    ) AS `devider`
FROM
    `categories` `c`
    JOIN `products` `p` ON `p`.`section_id` = `c`.`section_id`
    JOIN `orders_products` `op` ON `op`.`products_id` = `p`.`products_id`
    JOIN `orders_total` `ot` ON `ot`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
WHERE
    `c`.`section_id` = 25
AND
    `p`.`product_type` IN ('P')
AND
    `ot`.`class` IN ('ot_shipping')
GROUP BY `op`.`orders_id`
```

The main problem is that I getting error

`#1054 - Unknown column 'op.orders_id' in 'where clause'`

And can't run this. I have separated query in my loop but that made performance issue and want to push it in one query. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing sub-sub query and use `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)`

```
SELECT
    (CAST(`ot`.`value` AS DECIMAL(6,2))) AS `value`,
    `op`.`orders_id`,
    (
        SELECT
           COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(`op2`.`concert_date`,' ',`op2`.`concert_time`))
        FROM
          `orders_products` `op2`
        WHERE
          `op2`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
        AND
           `op2`.`concert_date` <> ''
    ) AS `devider`
FROM
    `categories` `c`
    JOIN `products` `p` ON `p`.`section_id` = `c`.`section_id`
    JOIN `orders_products` `op` ON `op`.`products_id` = `p`.`products_id`
    JOIN `orders_total` `ot` ON `ot`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
WHERE
    `c`.`section_id` = 25
AND
    `p`.`product_type` IN ('P')
AND
    `ot`.`class` IN ('ot_shipping')
GROUP BY `op`.`orders_id`
```

and you don't even need subquery or concat as long concert_date or concert_time is null

```
SELECT
    (CAST(`ot`.`value` AS DECIMAL(6,2))) AS `value`,
    `op`.`orders_id`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `op`.`concert_date`, `op`.`concert_time`) AS `devider`
FROM
    `categories` `c`
    JOIN `products` `p` ON `p`.`section_id` = `c`.`section_id`
    LEFT JOIN `orders_products` `op` ON `op`.`products_id` = `p`.`products_id`
    JOIN `orders_total` `ot` ON `ot`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
WHERE
    `c`.`section_id` = 25
AND
    `p`.`product_type` IN ('P')
AND
    `ot`.`class` IN ('ot_shipping')
GROUP BY `op`.`orders_id`
```

Comment: The second one is perfect, other give wrong result in `devider`. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

In this subquery:

```
SELECT
                `op2`.`concert_date`
            FROM
                `orders_products` `op2`
            WHERE
                `op2`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
            AND
                `op2`.`concert_date` <> ''
            GROUP BY CONCAT(`op2`.`concert_date`,' ',`op2`.`concert_time`)
```

you are not selecting op as table.
Should be:

```
SELECT
                `op2`.`concert_date`
            FROM
                `orders_products` `op2`, `orders_products` `op`
            WHERE
                `op2`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
            AND
                `op2`.`concert_date` <> ''
            GROUP BY CONCAT(`op2`.`concert_date`,' ',`op2`.`concert_time`)
```

Beside this you are making an implicit join while you should use explicit even here and the subquery should become:

```
SELECT
                `op2`.`concert_date`
            FROM
                `orders_products` `op2` JOIN `orders_products` `op`
            ON
                `op2`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
            WHERE
                `op2`.`concert_date` <> ''
            GROUP BY CONCAT(`op2`.`concert_date`,' ',`op2`.`concert_time`)
```

Comment: "you are not selecting op as table." i think that's the reason, he wanted to use `op` from main, outer query. the problem is `op` is not available in sub-sub query. with your answer the sub query always returns same value which makes no sense